# How to handle negative or unsigned char when porting from C/C++ to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, casting, fromcharcode

I'm trying to port an old C++ lexer ([source](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius/blob/6d135a686a74376495a7a6f55d3d67df54186f83/gramtools/mkdfa/mkfa-1.44-flex/lex.yy.c)) to JavaScript and am struggling a bit with my non-comprehension of C/C++.

I have a parameter `c` which as I currently see it could either be an index of the position on a chunk of an input file I'm parsing (`*yy_cp`) or the actual (including nul) character stored at this address. I need to use `c` as an index in a lookup table. The lexer does this:

```
/* Promotes a possibly negative, possibly signed char to an
 * unsigned integer for use as an array index.  If the signed char
 * is negative, we want to instead treat it as an 8-bit unsigned
 * char, hence the double cast.
 */
#define YY_SC_TO_UI(c) ((unsigned int) (unsigned char) c)
```

and calls it like this:

```
register YY_CHAR yy_c = yy_ec[YY_SC_TO_UI(*yy_cp)];
```

which will store the value of lookup table `yy_ec` which contains 256 entries (I assume extended ASCII), in `yy_c`. The position to lookup is generated by `YY_SC_TO_UI` and that's where I'm lost porting this to JavaScript. `YY_SC_TO_UI` has to return a number between 0-255, so do I just take what I have and:

```
 "[c]".charCodeAt(0)
```

or are ia there anything else I need to be aware of handling "possible negative, possible signed char" in JS?

Thanks.

Comment: Ew. Are you sure you want to use this code?

Comment: yeah, at least not all the comments are in Japanese... :) Once or if I ever have it working, I'm dreaming of a clean rewrite in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on a compiler `char` can be `signed` or `unsigned`. Presumably author wanted this to work on both the same way, and make sure that value is always zero extended, and not sign extended, when converting from `char` to `unsigned int`. A safe way to make sure the value is 0..255, and not -128..127.

[According to MDN, range of return value of charCodeAt is larger:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

> The charCodeAt() method returns an integer between 0 and 65535...

It depends on your input how you want to handle possible values out of range, but one alternative could be simple bit masking:

```
"€".charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;
```

Comment: sexy... might add https://oscarliang.com/what-s-the-use-of-and-0xff-in-programming-c-plus-p/ for sake of completeness